# How is CAM implemented?

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design, memory, cache

I have a book statement:

> A content addressable memory is a circuit that combines comparison and storage in a single device.

I want to know how this is implemented in real world? Sounds like an bitwise-and(&) which does the job in instant? But won't this cause the size of the circuit increase?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Semiconductor_implementations do some re-search

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist: I've read that, it's vague. Could you provide an graphical answer? And I found people don't prefer reading wiki for *research*.

Comment: I think it is very clear.  It is like an explicit "google search" for a keyword ( with no ads ;)with a table of results except this list is an address table from memory .  Search *cisco CAM table* for examples.

Comment: A single FF stores. A single EXOR does comparison.